# Reversing order of numbers in linked list recursivly

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I want to reverse the order of numbers in a linked list with recursion.

(1,(2,(3,( )))) ----> (3,(2,(1,( ))))

My linked lists, are nested tuples. First(xs) returns the first element, in the above example it would be either 1 or 3 on the right side. Rest(xs) returns all other elements, (2,(3,( ))) or (2,(1,( ) on the right side.

my code looks like this:

```
empty = ()
def reversed(xs):
    if xs == (first(xs), empty):
        return first(xs)
    else:
        return reversed(rest(xs)), first(xs)
```

but it yields in following output:

```
((3, 2), 1)
```

I guess, I'm pretty close, but I'm running out of ideas how to fix this.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you writing Haskell code in python? The result will be neither readable nor fast.

Comment: Show us your linked list class.

Comment: Hint: use an *accumulator*.

Comment: @Aran-Fey where is this Haskell code? I forgot some indentation, did you mean that?  It's written in python.

Comment: @DocDriven There is no class. The OP's linked list is a bunch of nested tuples.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you're writing functional-style code in an imperative language. Your code would be good Haskell code. It's not good python code.

Comment: @Peet, python is a multi-paradigm language. It supports programming in many styles: imperative, object-oriented, functional, procedural, etc. Sure, the feature set suggests Python favors some styles over others, but don't let that stop you from using a style of your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this. Right now, you are merely concatenating them to a new tuple, which does not create a properly formed linked list. Instead, you could `append` the former `first` to the `reversed` `rest` using a second function. Also, your base-case seems to be wrong, as you return just a single element instead of a linked list.

```
def reversed(xs):
    if xs == empty:
        return empty
    else:
        return append(reversed(rest(xs)), first(xs))

def append(xs, x):
    if xs == empty:
        return (x, empty)
    else:
        return first(xs), append(rest(xs), x)

>>> reversed((1, (2, (3, (4, empty)))))
(4, (3, (2, (1, ()))))
```

Note, however, that this has quadratic complexity O(n²) as you have to iterate the entire list (or partial list) to `append` the `first` node in each step of the `reversed` function. For a linear complexity O(n) version, you could add a second paramter to your `reversed` function (or create a second function to be called by the original function if you can't change the signature). This will build the reversed list in that second parameter and finally just return that list.

```
def reversed(xs, tail=empty):
    if xs == empty:
        return tail
    else:
        return reversed(rest(xs), (first(xs), tail))
```

Also, as noted in comments, there are better languages for defining recursive data structures than Python, and better ways to use lists in Python, but I'll assume that this is just for learning and not for practical use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion:

```
d = (1,(2,(3,())))
def reverse(_d, _c = ()):
  a, b = _d
  return (a, _c) if not b else reverse(b, (a, _c))

print(reverse(d))
```

Output:

```
(3, (2, (1, ())))
```

Comment: Please correct me if I'm missing something, but isn't this the same as my second version?

Comment: @tobias_k I did not see your second version when I posted, but the general idea is certainly the same. I think my answer is a bit cleaner and certainly shorter, but I can delete this if you wish, however.

Comment: No problem, I was just a bit stumped. (BTW, I agree on the _shorter_ part, but...)